# How I can change styles of power bi embed?

Tags: angular, typescript, powerbi, embed

```
I made a site that includes powerbi embedded.
```

In mobile version, i want to make a margin-left to center reports.

```
 Here's my config parameters

settings: this.isMobile ? {
                filterPaneEnabled: this.reportConfig.filterPaneEnabled,
                navContentPaneEnabled: this.reportConfig.navContentPaneEnabled,
                layoutType: 0,
                customLayout: {
                    displayOption: 1
                }
            } :
                {
                    filterPaneEnabled: this.reportConfig.filterPaneEnabled,
                    navContentPaneEnabled: this.reportConfig.navContentPaneEnabled
                }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can make a mobile friendly version in PowerBI itself and it will detect when it is in mobile state.

1) In Report View in Power BI Desktop, on the View tab, select Phone Layout. ...
2) To add a visual to the phone layout, drag it from the Visualizations pane to the phone canvas.

you can add a white visual...